# vue3 computed set doesn't work when get an object binding v-model

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

```
 <script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'

const user = computed({
  get() {
    // return props.user
    return { 
      name: 'mike',
      age: 18
    }
  },
  set(value) {
    // it doesn't work
    console.log(value)
  }
})

</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="user.name" type="text">
  <input v-model="user.age" type="number">
</template>
```

the props.user is dynamic value so i used computed getter get the real time result.
i think vue computed doesn't deep watching object property change. how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<script setup>
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue'

const user = reactive({ name: 'Mike', age: 18 })
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="user.name" type="text">
  <input v-model="user.age" type="number">
    {{ user.name}} {{ user.age }}
</template>
```

[Link to the vue playground with that code](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UMtOwzAQ/JWVLwGpScQNRSkSH8Af7CVNt8WhfsheB5Dlf2ed8jr15hnPzowmq2fvuzWRGtQY56A9QyRO/gmtNt4FhgyBppn1SjuYnfGJ6QgFTsEZaOSyQYt2djYypEgB9r/6uwx2MjRA86LfqNnBdBbw8AjlHu3YX+MkSACT8ZeJSRDAqK2kwNoad6TLHlX17aoVKuBPT0IxfTCqG3LJ+lPbZA4UNj1yzlvRzbAU+IFyAKXUYv/KoFU7dR2iNZPvluisTJVrLn5/RFQDbEzlZJGKUb0y+zj0fTzNdeAldi6ce3l1IVnWhjqKpj0E917TF3GpFlKgqPIFsUOOXg==)

In Vue3 you have to use `ref` and `reactive` to do this deep dynamic watching, but I am not sure how it will work with props